# prime-ng p-toast in app component not displaying messages sent from other components

Tags: angular, primeng

In order to reduce the amount of primeng toast components (p-toast) in my webapp I tried to use a central p-toast with key in app.component. Then I add messages from other components using the messageservice with the key of that toast component. Unfortunately the toasts are not being shown.

my app.component.html

```
<div>
  <app-header></app-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <app-footer *ngIf="!userLoggedIn"></app-footer>
</div>
<p-toast [style]="{ marginTop: '80px' }" key="myToast"></p-toast>
```

my app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  providers: [MessageService]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    private readonly messageService: MessageService
  ) {...
```

from within a component (shown through routeroutlet) I add a message:

```
  this.messageService.add({
    severity: 'success',
    summary: 'Success Message',
    key: 'myToast',
    detail: 'Order submitted'
  });
```

I also tried the following alternatives:

```
this.ngZone.run(() => {
  this.messageService.add({
    severity: 'success',
    summary: 'Success Message',
    key: 'myToast',
    detail: 'Order submitted'
  });
});
```

and

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.messageService.add({
    severity: 'success',
    summary: 'Success Message',
    key: 'myToast',
    detail: 'Order submitted'
  });
}, 1000);
```

None of this works.

Did I forget something? Or is p-toast not ment to be used like that?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You just need to change a few more things

1) Add ToastModule to the AppModule imports list

2) Add MessageService to the AppModule providers list

3) Remove MessageService from providers array in any other component, you can still import MessageService and do `this.messageService.add` from any component

Then try it out